# Counter-examples of right-continuous filtrations

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

A filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)$ is said to be right continuous if $\mathcal{F}_t =
\bigcap\limits_{h > 0} \mathcal{F}_{t + h}$.  (A filtration $( \mathcal{F}_t)$ is a collection such that
each $\mathcal{F}_t$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that $\mathcal{F}_s \subset
\mathcal{F}_t$ if $s \leqslant t$).

What are some counter-examples about filtrations failing to be right
continuous?

Answer (score 4):

Take any discrete filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}$ and define $\mathscr{F}_t:= \mathcal{F}_{f(t)}$ for any left continuous increasing $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{N}$.
Note: such an $f$ cannot be right continuous as well, else it would be continuous and the codomain could not be $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\Omega$ be the space of continuous paths from $[0,\infty)$ to ${\Bbb R}$, and let $(X_t)$ be the coordinate process defined by $X_t(\omega) = \omega(t)$ for $t\ge 0$ and $\omega\in\Omega$. The filtration ${\cal F}_t:=\sigma\{X_s:0\le s\le t\}$, $t\ge 0$, is not right continuous. Indeed, the event $\Omega_+$, defined as
$$
\Omega_+:=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{r\in{\Bbb Q, r<1/n}}\{\omega\in\Omega: X_r(\omega) >0\},
$$
is an element of $\bigcap\limits_{h>0}{\cal F}_h$ but is not an element of ${\cal F}_0=\sigma\{X_0\}$.

Comment: I do not understand why $ \Omega_+ $ does not belong to $ \mathcal F_0 $ ? I work on it but I have not found why. Please might someone write the argument ?